# Is it possible to combine the following classes into a single generic class?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the following classes...

**LetterScore.cs**

```
public class LetterScore {
    public char Letter;
    public int Score;

    public LetterScore(char c = ' ', int score = 0) {
        Letter = c;
        Score = score;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"LETTER:{Letter}, SCORE:{Score}";
}
```

**LetterPoint.cs**

```
public class LetterPoint {
    public char Letter;
    public Point Position;

    public LetterPoint(char c = ' ', int row = 0, int col = 0) {
        Letter = c;
        Position = new Point(row, col);
    }

    public string PositionToString => $"(X:{Position.X}Y:{Position.Y})";
    public override string ToString() => $"(LETTER:{Letter}, POSITION:{PositionToString})";
}
```

Is there anything I can do with `LINQ` or generic variables (eg. T) that could combine these two classes into a single class?

> I wish to do this because there may be further classes down the line
>   of my project that require alterations to the format of these classes
>   (eg. each class has a letter and a value corresponding to a certain
>   situation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with generics:

```
public class Letter<T>
{
    public char Letter {get;set;}
    public T Item {get;set;} /*or make this protected and expose it in your derived class */
}

public class LetterPoint : Letter<Point>
{
    public LetterPoint(char c = ' ', int row = 0, int col = 0)
    {
        Letter = c;
        Item = new Point(row, col);
    }

    public string PositionToString => $"(X:{Item.X}Y:{Item.Y})";
    public override string ToString() => $"(LETTER:{Letter}, POSITION:{PositionToString})";

}

public class LetterScore : Letter<int>
{

    public LetterScore(char c = ' ', int score = 0)
    {
        Letter = c;
        Item = score;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"LETTER:{Letter}, SCORE:{Item}";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity It should compile now.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus - You should let Robert fix his own answer.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus - Or you could post the compiling code as your own answer, but still mark Robert's as the correct one.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'll be sure to do that next time.